# Investigating night time shut downs

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, troubleshooting

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 install (AMD FX-4100 quad core, 32gb) is shutting down around 2:30 am every other night.

I've updated the motherboard BIOS but that hasn't helped.

I ran AUTORUNS.EXE to see if there was anything unexpected in the processes that start automatically but found nothing. (Output of AUTORUNS available.)

I'm considering upgrading to 2012 R2 (there's no supported direct upgrade to 2016 from 2008 R2).

Any thoughts on how I might trouble shoot this as I'm at a loss.

Comment: Have you looked in the System event log for events on or around that time?

Comment: Windows updates?

Comment: @joeqwerty I've looked previously and didn't see anything helpful in the System log. Unfortunately today, some script kiddy has launched a dictionary attack on my server and the early morning events from today right before the shutdown have scrolled off in the Security and System logs.

Comment: @LHWizard I thought that too but every other day? Checking Windows Update shows the last check was yesterday at 9:40 and last install was Wednesday, March 14th at 3:08 am. The server shut down on the 13th around 2:39 am* and on the 15th around 2:38*.  * time stamp of when the server down text message was received.